# Showing success icon in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome

As I migrated from bootstrap 3.3.7 to Bootstrap 4, I learned of glyphicon being discontinued. So how to show success using font-awesome? What is the font-awesome equivalent for glyphicon-ok? 
Does Anyone out here have a font-awesome equivalent sheet for all glyphicon icons.

Comment: This is not that hard to find: http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: Fontawesome cheatsheet http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font Awesome assigns other name: "check". HTML icon is: `<i class="fa fa-check"></i>`.